# django-endless-pagination django-pagination records index on page and total

Tags: django, pagination, django-pagination, django-endless-pagination

Is there an option to see records index on the current page and total?

For example:

> Records 51-100, 980 total

on page #2

I could maybe use a `{% with object_list.count as "pages_total" %}` templatetag then lots of code.. and {% endwith %} at the end code.. - done before the `{% paginate %}` or `{% autopaginate %}` but this doesn't seem to be a nice solution. Also it makes another db call.

I can't find this in documentation, and `{{ object_list.count }}` gives 50 in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Django Endless Pagination 2.0, you will able to use this in your template:

```
{% load endless %}
{% paginate entries %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {# your code to show the entry #}
{% endfor %}
{% get_pages %}
Showing entries 
{{ pages.current_start_index }}-{{ pages.current_end_index }} of
{{ pages.total_count }}.
{{ pages }}
```

All this is in [Django-endless-pagination document](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/digg_pagination.html#showing-indexes)

Answer (score 1):

People tend to overcomplicate this. I found thee current_start_index and current_end_index functions fairly well documented in the source ( but not in the actual documentation ).

Here is how you would use them to achieve that.

{{ pages.current_start_index }} through {{ pages.current_end_index }} of {{ pages.total_count }} results

Hope this helps someone :D

Answer (score 0):

All django-pagination paginators extends Django's built-in [Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#django.core.paginator.Paginator) class. The best solution is to use [`Paginator.count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#attributes) to get the total number of elements on all pages (if you're passing `QuerySet` object to the `Paginator`). According to the doc:

> When determining the number of objects contained in object_list, Paginator will first try calling object_list.count(). If object_list has no count() method, then Paginator will fallback to using len(object_list). This allows objects, such as Django's QuerySet, to use a more efficient count() method when available.

So yes, it will do another DB query, but it's unavoidable if you do not know the number of elements. Django will use `count()` which uses `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement, which is the best way to get number of rows.

Comment: That will make including pagination div harder. Using `{% include "paginator.html" %}`. Both solutions I mentioned are aware of total objects count.. they must have it because they split queryset to parts. I am just curious why there is no `{% pages.total_count %}` template tag, or variable available -or maybe I'm missing something dome docs here.

Comment: Why it'll make including pagination div harder?

Comment: You have to keep a `{{ total_count }}` from `{% with object_list.count as "total_count" %}`. Only then You can use paginator div (which shows total count of records). I think that If either django-pagination or django-endless-pagination provided such variable this would be easier. The code would be cleaner, and one less query would hit the db. Simply loading pagination_tags and then autopaginating object list + including paginator div (that's how I actually do it now) would be better - I don't have total count & current page start/end index.

Comment: Can you provide 'paginator.html' code? I believie you can add the 'total_count' to the context in [pagination_tags.py](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/source/browse/trunk/pagination/templatetags/pagination_tags.py). It's like one line of code.

Comment: Currently I am using django-endless-pagination, and doing a new gmail like controls next/previous with `<a title="{% trans "Previous" %}" data-pjax="#dyna-content" href="{{ pages.previous.path }}" class="btn{% if not pages.previous %} disabled{% endif %}"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a title="{% trans "Next" %}" data-pjax="#dyna-content" href="{{ pages.next.path }}" class="btn{% if not pages.next %} disabled{% endif %}"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>` As for patching, yeah.. but my question could be "why so obvious total count var is missing (maybe it's not...)".